# Kriging metal concentration with irregular set of sample points

Tags: interpolation, spatial-statistics, kriging

I need to perform some interpolation to map a metal concentration around a platform. The distribution of my stations is not regular (see figure below where stations are the green points labelled with the relative metal concentration).

What is the correct procedure/method for kriging? Are there any other specific settings, techniques, or values to look at when dealing with my hotspots and kriging?

[image: station distribution]

Comment: What GIS are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS...QGIS as well

Comment: Have you tried using the concentration as the Z value within Spatial Analyst > Interpolation > Kriging in ArcGIS?

Comment: Yes, but just wondering which kriging method is the best (ordinary, Disjunctivec etc) and if there are any other specific settings, techniques, or values to look at when dealing withmy hotspots and kriging